# Go to new site when a button is clicked 

Tags: c#, silverlight, url, button

How can I do set up my button, so that when my button is clicked, I will open a new internet browser window and browse to an address (e.g walla.com)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does [this](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/21257.aspx) help?

It shows this example:

```
System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri(YourNewPageURL), "_blank", "toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,resizable=yes");
```

Comment: i wrote HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri("http://localhost:52878/DoNationFinalTestPage.aspx#/jjj"), "Organiztrion_info_from_toolTip");  is the window that i built, but it opens the application again in a new window and not the "Organiztrion_info_from_toolTip" window

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about about a web application you're best doing this using JavaScript

```
<input type="button" onclick="window.open('http://www.walla.com/')" />
```

Comment: Should use window.open to popup a new window.

Comment: it tells me that this event hendler (window.open('http://www.walla.com/')" ) is not in my class...
anyway, how can i do it in c# code? i donwt want to touch the xaml...

Answer (score 0):

Hey hi aharont , you can go for the hyper link button to make it simpler ,here is what you have to do :

```
<HyperlinkButton Content="Open" NavigateUri="http://www.walla.com" TargetName="_blank" />
```